# Apply a function across multiple axes of a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3-D numpy array of shape `(2, n, m)`, with `n,m` arbitrary, let's call `X`. I have two functions `F = F(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray)` and `G = G(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray)`, where `x` and `y` are 1-D arrays of lenght `m` and these functions returns 1-D array also of shape `m`. I want to apply a transformation to `X` the operates in the second axis, using `F` and `G`

```
for idx in range(n):
    X[0][idx], X[1][idx] = F(X[0][idx], X[1][idx]), G(X[0][idx], X[1][idx])
```

**Example**

Suposse `m = n = 2`, and let

```
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)


In [18]: X
Out[18]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])
```

And suppose that `F` and `G`are defined by (**dummy functions** these are not the real ones)

```
def F(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return x - y

def G(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return y - x
```

Then applying the transformation to X

```
for idx in range(2):
    X[0][idx], X[1][idx] = F(X[0][idx], X[1][idx]), G(X[0][idx], X[1][idx])
```

I get

```
In [23]: X
Out[23]: 
array([[[-4, -4], 
        [-4, -4]],

       [[ 4,  4],
        [ 4,  4]]])
```

**Example 2**

Consider `F = np.cross`, `G = -F` and `X =np.arange(12).reshape(2,2,3)`.

```
for idx in range(2):
    X[0][idx], X[1][idx] = np.cross(X[0][idx], X[1][idx]), - np.cross(X[0[idx], X[1][idx])
```

then,

```
In [49]: X
Out[49]: 
array([[[ -6,  12,  -6],
        [ -6,  12,  -6]],

       [[  6, -12,   6],
        [  6, -12,   6]]])
```

I reiterate that F and G are not the real functions, it should work for arbitrary definitions. I want a solution that doesn't use the for loop I wrote above

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.apply_along_axis`:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: [F(x[0], x[1]), G(x[0], x[1])], 0, X)
array([[[-4, -4],
        [-4, -4]],

       [[ 4,  4],
        [ 4,  4]]])
>>>
```

This applies the function to every subarray of your numpy array, as your original for loop does, it use `lambda` to map the functions to the values.

**Edit:**

You could try `zip` and `map`:

```
>>> np.array([*zip(*map(lambda x: [np.cross(x[0], x[1]), -np.cross(x[0], x[1])], zip(*X)))])
array([[[ -6,  12,  -6],
        [ -6,  12,  -6]],

       [[  6, -12,   6],
        [  6, -12,   6]]])
>>>
```

Comment: This works when the functions `F` and `G`  operate element by element in the arrays `x`,
in this case, adding and subtracting the coordinates of the vectors. It does not work for a general transformation

Comment: @Andrex What do you mean by `general transformation`?

Comment: @Andrex I solved your original problem, I would say you should mark this here and ask a new one

Comment: It's not solved, the typing says that functions operates in `np.ndarray` and returns `np.ndarray`. Your solution is operating elementwise. I will edit my question. I think the solution is close to what you wrote

Comment: @Andrex Could you please show your desired output for your new function?

Comment: @Andrex Oh sorry, was a bit busy, now I will try to solve

Comment: @Andrex Edited my answer with something that works